# Python FFT frequency of Guitar Note

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I've been trying to make a program to determine what note a guitar is playing. When I use this code with a sine wave, for example 440hz it works and get the frequency back correctly. However when I give it audio of a guitar playing one note the result is way off. For example I play a low E string on the guitar and would be expecting 82.41 but I get 18947.25. I am new to digital signal processing so I could be missing something fundamental that I don't know about. Any help would be a great help.

Cheers!

```
from scipy import fftpack
from scipy.io import wavfile as scipy_wav
import numpy as np

def get_frequency(filename):
    sample_rate, data = scipy_wav.read(filename)

    fft_out = fftpack.fft(data)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_out))

    # Find the peak in the coefficients
    idx = np.argmax(np.abs(fft_out))

    freq = freqs[idx]
    freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * sample_rate)
    return freq_in_hertz
```

Comment: a pure sin wave is rarely heard in the wild, certainly musical instruments like a guitar intentionally emit very complex audio where the note it plays is does have the most energy however symmetrically surrounded by a series of harmonics etc ... this is the challenge you face ... as with any audio project its of great help of have ability to visualize your audio curves, in your case both the guitar audio curve as well as the synthesized frequency the guitar is supposed to be playing

Comment: Did you try plotting the signal and its FFT decomposition? Maybe you have a sharp peak at an unexpected frequency due to some recording noise or another artifact? Also, I personally like the welch method in the signal module of scipy. Applying a peak finder on that output works for me in most cases. Try signal.welch(your_guitar_data, fs = your_sampling_rate, *optional params).

Comment: Recordings of low guitar notes can contain strong harmonics (overtones) with a strongly attenuated (or even missing) fundamental note pitch frequency.  Thus, don't use a bare fft magnitude max, since it will often give garbage results.

Comment: Using recorded audio data and determining the note played is a more complicated problem than you are assuming and is also asked every few weeks on stackoverflow. A good place to start would be to review some of the previous discussions.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I wasn't aware of the missing fundamental issue. Knowing that is a problem gives something more to search for. From brief reading, Cepstrum analysis seems like a possible solution.